# Python sys instead of exiting to continue

Tags: python, sys

I am making a calculator program, using the sys library, that when parentheses are not closed, it prints that it is not valid, it should be noted that it is in a while loop

```
sys.exit ("Incorrect answer")
>>Incorrect answer
>> Finishe the program
```

I already tried to do it with

```
print ("Incorrect answer")
>>Incorrect answer 
>>None
```

I have to make the program continue but if I use print it works but I get none

but I get none and I don't know why that is because someone knows of an alternative instead of using exit, a continue or something similar?

Comment: You get `None` because that is what `print` *returns*.

Comment: @ScottHunter is right. But I honestly don't know what you're asking. You don't show how your calculator works and what you expect it to return or do or what.

Comment: @ScottHunter thanks I am quite new in this world and I did not understand the difference between return and print but searching I found the solution and managed to understand a little more how it works thanks

Comment: @Mythalorian Yes, thank you, I did not want to publish all the code that is a final project and I wanted to avoid problems with my professor but I managed to solve it, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it instead of making a

```
print ("Incorrect answer")
>>Incorrect answer
>> None
```

use

```
return ("Incorrect answer")
>> Incorrect answer
```